# How to export a single Firefox extension(antivirus) as an installable xpi file?

Tags: firefox, anti-virus, firefox-extensions

I want to know how can i export my antivirus extension as an xpi file ??
i used FEBE add-on,but it was unable to backup  the extension .
I search all the net but no helpful way.

Comment: What about FEBE didn't work? How did you backup the extension and what happens (include any error messages) when you try to back it up? Also, what's the name of the extension?

Comment: the name of extension is:Qihoo 360 Internet Security, and the message of FEBE is:"the location of Qihoo 360 Internet Security extension could not found, press OK to skip this item."

Comment: Is there any way to export codes of this extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox anti-virus "extensions" are usually not extensions at all, but plug-ins masquerading as extensions.  FEBE cannot back these up as xpis because they are not built as regular extensions.  In fact, if you were to open the anti-virus xpi with a text editor you would most likely see just an URI to the actual code that gets executed.  These are what are known as "proxy" extensions and cannot be re-built as installable xpis (at least not with FEBE).

Another option would be to use FEBE's user-defined backup function.  If you know the location of the extension, you can create a backup item in *FEBE Options > What to backup > User-defined backups*.

Comment: thanks a lot.I understand that when i read your answers here[link](www.customsoftwareconsult.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1356&sid=7626fd442b7150c68d2f06a1f9d0776e) .but now i want to know how can i export codes of this extension of course if  it is possible.because internet download manger app extension there is on net for download as a xpi file while  that extension   in real it's a plugin